# What are the exceptions where the width of a block-level element does not rely on the width of its parent?

Tags: html, css

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html:

> Normally, all block-level elements take 100% of the width of their
>   parent (there are exceptions, but let’s ignore them for now). So the
>   `<body>` is as wide as its parent, the `<html>` element.

What are the exceptions where the width of a block-level element when set to 100% does not give us the same width of its parent?

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged [javascript]...

Comment: But this question isn't *about* JavaScript.

Comment: Probably someone who looks at JavaScript questions saw that it had nothing to do with JavaScript and downvoted you :)

Comment: that's my guess too, but it is still useful to know who are doing the downvotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the default setting of `width: auto` (for obvious reasons), one exception I can think of is when the child element's computed `position` is anything other than `static` or `relative`.

Another exception I can think of is with floated child elements: these are always crunched to the minimum content width unless you manually set their `width` property.

Comment: to be clear, you do mean only when `position` is `absolute` or `fixed`. right?

Comment: response to edit: btw, just to add actually I was talking about when when position of child is set to `100%`